# background app in iOS that detects incoming phone calls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I need to write a background application in iOS which listens to incoming phone calls on the iPhone.

Is it possible? Can anyone suggest some good pointers ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 6):

This would be very much against Apple's privacy policy and there's no chance an app like this would be approved.

[There are call recording apps that sneak](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/callrec.me/id343580672?mt=8) [around this restriction, though](http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-phones/how-to-record-calls-on-an-iphone-for-free-50005584/), but they use third party services and no actual built-in iPhone API's.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in applicationWillEnterForeground  using CTCallCenter's CTCallState properties. Don't forget to import the CoreTelephony framework. Here's an example:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call) {
        if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateIncoming] || [[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateDialing]) {

            if ([viewController isPlaying])
            {
                NSLog(@"Call was started.");
            }
        } else if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateDisconnected]) {
            if (callWasStarted)
            {
               NSLog(@"Call was ended.");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: You can edit your own answers without having to create duplicates :)