# Using IOS SDK is it possible to detect an incoming call when another call is inprogress (in background)?

Tags: iphone, ios, background-process, core-telephony

I am aware that we can get the `call state` info using `CoreTelephony` framework (using `CTCallCenter`).If a call is already in progress,is it possible to detect the new incoming call and one more thing is it possible to track the incoming calls in the background application.

[Detecting call state in iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4)

[background app in iOS that detects incoming phone calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891503/background-app-in-ios-that-detects-incoming-phone-calls)

From the above links, I think it is not possible to run the app in `background`.Is there any other approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible with the current sdk.